# Load multiple CSVs, extract file name append as column and archive SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

OK I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I have a 'Orders Folder' that contains CSV files.  I need to loop through the  csv files, load them into a SQL table, and then move the csv's into a 'Archive Folder'.  I want to perform this in SSIS and know this is possible using a Foreach loop container, which I understand.

The CSV file has the following headings:

Customer / Item / Qty / Date

My SQL table has the following headings:

Customer / Item / Qty / Date / User

The tricky bit is the csv files contain the username for each order and are named like this:  (USERNAME obviously changes)

FWD_Order_USERNAME_01_02_2016_1006_214.csv

I need to extract the USERNAME and append it to the SQL table for each csv file when it is imported - how do I do this?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: What does "append it to the SQL table" mean?   Add it as a column?   a row?   Something else?

Comment: sorry - extract the username from the csv file name and insert it into the User field in the SQL table

Comment: How do you know what the user name? Is it the third entity delimited by `_`?

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a package variable with the username from the file name, and use a Derived Column transformation to add it as a new column in your dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are using for each loop to process the files.
 You must be storing file name in variable.

1) Create one more variable **user** name and using expression set value property  expression(to get user name ), set property EvaluateAsExpression = true; for variable.

2) In data flow add derived column using **user variable**  map this to user column in destination.